# Get values (floating type) from pgfplottsables

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'm trying to get certain values from a table a created from a csv file.
I'm want those values to plot them.
The problem is when I'm extrating those values, it seems that they are no longer a floating type.

```
% 1-Importing all values from CSV file.
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{allValues.csv}\allValues

% 2-Getting the values I want to plot.
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{X, Y
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]2}\of\allValues \pgfplotsretval,\pgfplotstablegetelem{2}{[index]2}\of\allValues \pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]3}\of\allValues \pgfplotsretval,\pgfplotstablegetelem{2}{[index]3}\of\allValues \pgfplotsretval
}\plotValues

% 3-Plotting
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend columns=1,
grid=both, 
]
\addplot[only marks, mark=o] table {\plotValues};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Any thoughts ? Or is there a simpliest way to achieve that ?

Here's the content of the allValues.csv file:

```
Name;Unit;Values1;Values2;Values3
N_fan;rpm;1300;1600;1300
T_out;°C;11.3;13.6;20.2
T_1;°C;46.5;54.8;45.3
T_2;°C;56.4;61.8;58
T_3;°C;114.1;116.6;92
```

Comment: if you added some glimpse of `allValues.csv` it would be easier to understand what your are aiming at.

Comment: Just added it .

Comment: Your provided MWE doesn't even compile...

Comment: That's why I need help....... If you replace the `pgfplotstablegetelem` lines with random numbers it compliles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Name;Unit;Values1;Values2;Values3
N_fan;rpm;1300;1600;1300
T_out;°C;11.3;13.6;20.2
T_1;°C;46.5;54.8;45.3
T_2;°C;56.4;61.8;58
T_3;°C;114.1;116.6;92
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xinttools}

\makeatletter
\let\firstoftwo\@firstoftwo
\let\secondoftwo\@secondoftwo
\makeatother
\begin{document}
% 1-Importing all values from CSV file.
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{\jobname.csv}\allValues

%\show\allValues
% 2-Getting the values I want to plot.
\newcommand\setupmytable{}%
\newcommand\mysep{}%
\newcommand\mycrcr{}

\def\setupmytable{X, Y}%
\let\mysep\firstoftwo
\let\mycrcr\relax

\xintForpair #1#2 in {(0, 2), (2, 2), (0, 3), (2, 3)}:
{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{[index]#2}\of\allValues
    \edef\setupmytable{\setupmytable \mysep{\mycrcr}{,}\pgfplotsretval}%
    \mysep{\let\mysep\secondoftwo}{\let\mysep\firstoftwo}%
}

\def\mycrcr{\noexpand\\\space}
\edef\setupmytable{\noexpand\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, row sep=crcr]%
              {\setupmytable\mycrcr}\noexpand\plotValues}

\setupmytable

% 3-Plotting
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend columns=1,
grid=both, 
]
\addplot[only marks, mark=o] table {\plotValues};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Regarding the `\xintForpair` it would probably be more logical to have two nested `\xintFor` the outer one for the row index, the inner one for the column index, but when I started this I wasn't sure what the original syntax met. (I use some trick with `\mysep`, limited to only two columns, which would not be needed, if the approach had been with two nested `\xintFor`)

Exceptionally (I mean, in comparison to most users asking questions on this site) I opened up the documentation of `pgfplotstable` and I think doc of `/pgfplots/table/row sep=newline|\\` on page 7 is relevant.

[image]

```
> \setupmytable=macro:
->\pgfplotstableread [col sep=comma, row sep=crcr]{X, Y\\ 1300,46.5\\ 1600,54.8\\ }\plotValues .
l.46 \show\setupmytable
```

---

---

Truthful to my promise of reading the manual I now have a pure `pgfplotstable` way, but it is complicated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Name;Unit;Values1;Values2;Values3
N_fan;rpm;1300;1600;1300
T_out;°C;11.3;13.6;20.2
T_1;°C;46.5;54.8;45.3
T_2;°C;56.4;61.8;58
T_3;°C;114.1;116.6;92
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
% 1-Importing all values from CSV file.
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{\jobname.csv}\allValues

% 2-Getting the values I want to plot.

% c'est-à-dire il semble vouloir la colonne X avec les entrées 2 et 3 de la
% première rangée et la colonne Y constituée avec les entrées 2 et 3 de la
% de la troisième rangée

% Thus this is some kind of partial transpose

\pgfplotstablevertcat\morethanallValues\allValues

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
    columns = {},
    create col/assign/.code={%
        \edef\entry
          {\ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0 X\else
            \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=2 Y\else
              \pgfplotstablerow\fi\fi}
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
    }]
    {extra}\morethanallValues

%\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\morethanallValues

\pgfplotstabletranspose[columns={Values1,Values2,extra},
                        colnames from=extra,
                        input colnames to=]\plotValues\morethanallValues

%\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\plotValues

% surely there must be simpler way to get a table from some other
% with some columns selected... (I mean before \pgfplotstabletypeset
% which is not used here)

\pgfplotstabletranspose[columns={X,Y}]\plotValues\plotValues
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\plotValues

\pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=colnames,
                        input colnames to=]\plotValues\plotValues



%\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\plotValues
%\end{document}

% 3-Plotting
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend columns=1,
grid=both, 
]
\addplot[only marks, mark=o] table {\plotValues};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was more looking for explanations about why my way doesn't work. But you provided working alternatives so it's great.

Comment: For why your way does not work, I think there are possibly two main reasons: 1. first of all you define a macro, so the "inline" definition of table has a problem that end of lines look like spaces, see discussion or "row sep" key, 2. you use non-expandable macros to inject  the cell values: it is to be expected that `pgfplotstable` needs to find in a table definition the actual elements, not recipes to obtain the element, for this you would need  some other syntax rather than simply injecting a `\pgfplotsretval` which from the point of view of TeX is a macro like any other which needs ...

Comment: ...at some point to expand. One could imagine some syntax like  `....arbitrary macros resulting in the wished value to be stored in \pgfplotsretval... \SetThisCellTo{\pgfplotsretval}` but no such syntax seems to be provided by package.